# Write parquet to s3 using C# on the .NET 4.8 framework

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Apologies for a basic question, but I am a beginner and really want to understand this. How would I write a parquet file to AWS S3 using C# running on the .NET 4.8 framework?

I checked NuGet for AWSSDK.S3 and it seems like 4.8 is not supported. Or am I missing something?

Comment: AWSSDK.S3 is compatible with .NET Framework 4.8: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.S3#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: ok cool thanks! I thought it was only compatible with 4.5.

Comment: The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. [4.5 went out of support in 2016](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/). AWS (or any major cloud vendor) would never release something that only worked on unsupported runtimes. They'd have to support Framework bugs along with their own

Comment: Depending on what kind of APIs you use, you might also need AWSSDK.Extensions.CrtIntegration NuGet.  It should work with Framework 4.x just fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Convert.ToBase64String() to take your bytes to a Base64 string
- Use IAmazonS3.PutObjectAsync() async method to send the data
- It needs a PutObjectRequest object; it returns a PutObjectResponse object.

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you're uploading a file or an object to S3.  It's also not clear if you could use a higher-level abstraction, a different service, to store your data.